# Как передать фокус в окно, унаследованное от QQuickView при его создании в системе без менеджера окон?

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

Или в его корневой `QQuickItem`.

Суть в том, чтобы принимать нажатия клавиш на **уровне qml**, так как там уже созданно ряд функций, но если окно не в фокусе (например расколлибровался тач-скрин и нет возможности ткнуть в окно), то не принимает нажатия, которые их запускают (хотя "вообще" клавиши принимаются, но не идут внуть qml, а переделывать там целая проблема - там обрабатывается комбинации нажатия одних и отпускания других клавиш. Так что передача фокуса было бы самым простым решением, но ни одной функции в документации `QQuickView` и `QWindow` не нашел. Нашел было свойство Item activeFocus, но и оно оказалось readonly.

Среди флагов (`setFlags`) тоже ничего подходящего не нашел.

Comment: Может `QWindow::requestActivate()`?

Comment: @alexis031182 не, чего-то не сработало. На оконной системе, но с установленным флагом Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint тоже не срабатывает (если щелкнуть, только тогда)

Comment: Что-то нет больше ничего. Разве что `raise()` перед `requestActivate()` попробовать сделать. Для виндовса есть даже специальные `setWindowActivationBehavior()`, но для линукса почему-то более ничего.

Comment: @alexis031182 тоже нет. Похоже кьюти опирается на менеджер окон у себя внури. Копну уровнем ниже